# Getting AttributeError while importing grequests in Python 3.4

Tags: python, grequests

I've been trying to use **grequests** for asyncronous HTTP requests in my Python project, however I got an **AttribteError** and have been searching for solution for hours.

Here's my testing code:

```
import grequests

urls = ['htt://google.com', 'http://yahoo.com', 'http://bing.com']
unsent_request = (grequests.get(url) for url in urls)
results = grequests.map(unsent_request)
print(results)
```

And the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<censored>", line 1, in <module>
        import grequests
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\grequests.py", line 21, in <module>
        curious_george.patch_all(thread=False, select=False)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gevent\monkey.py", line 195, in patch_all
        patch_socket(dns=dns, aggressive=aggressive)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gevent\monkey.py", line 124, in patch_socket
        from gevent import socket
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gevent\socket.py", line 119, in <module>
        _fileobject = __socket__._fileobject
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_fileobject'
```

I've tried to uninstall and re-install both grequests and the whole Python, however the problem still exists.

I also tried to avoid using grequest (and use gevent), but the same problem happened.

After some search, I believe the closest problem I can find is this one:

[python3: socket._fileobject removed #434](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/issues/434)

But it seems not very trivial for me, and the solution provided is for SSL-related stuff.

If you have any solution or similar problem please share, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem. After

```
pip3 install --user --upgrade gevent==1.1rc3
```

the code executed without problems (`--user` is optional).